# A way to prevent automatic placeholder input type date in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, date, input, placeholder

I'm trying to create a form but I don't want to use labels, I just want to use the placeholder to let the user know what is asked from him.
But when I give it type="date" the placeholder in Chrome is ignored and replaced with: day-month-year, but I want it to display: Date of birth.

I there a way to do this? Otherwise I have to change the entire form and insert labels.

I know it's been asked before, but everyone wants to prevent the datepicker to display, I do like the datepicker but just not placeholder. All answers I found were based on the placeholder.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574356/html5-placeholder-disappears-on-focus

This jQuery plug in should stop that happening.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860851/how-do-i-change-the-html5-placeholder-text-that-appears-in-date-field-in-chrome

Comment: This can be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25018653/remove-placeholder-from-date-type-input-in-chrome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove default text/placeholder present in html5 input element of type=date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28686288/remove-default-text-placeholder-present-in-html5-input-element-of-type-date)

Answer (score 2):

The `placeholder` attribute is [not valid on input `type="date"`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-input-element.html#input-type-attr-summary).  So the easiest way to get `placeholder` to work is to set the `type` to something that supports it.

Also [note](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-placeholder):

> The placeholder attribute should not be used as an alternative to a
>   label.

If you are determined to use your approach you should add labels to your form then [make sure they're available to assistive technology](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/now-you-see-me/).

Comment: Well this explains why `placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD"` doesn't work... but how to set a type to something that support it when you need the native date input?