# how to configure default value of html date input

Tags: html, input

I know that the html date input field defaults to `"mm/dd/yyyy"`, but was wondering if there was a way to overwrite that with text to say something like "pick a date".

I have tried changing the `value` and `placeholder` attributes like so:

```
<input type="date" placeholder="Pick a Date">
<input type="date" value="Pick a Date">
```

but it ultimately doesn't seem to work as I assume it's expecting some sort of ISO date. Any ideas?

Example in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AY2mp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to use the jQuery date selector that uses an input field instead of date field so that the `value` and `placeholder` attributes can be used:

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

html

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" value="The Date">
```

js

```
$(function() {
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could do it like this. I am no javascript guru so there may be a more efficient way to do it, but it gets the job done.

Of course you will need to change the selectors.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ce2P7/

**HTML**

```
<div class="date1">
<input type="text" placeholder="Please choose a date" value="">
</div>
<div class="date2">
<input class="date" type="date" value="">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.date1 {
width: 150px; /* For consistency */
}
.date2 {
width: 150px; /* For consistency */
display: none;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $("input").one("click", function () {
  $(".date1").hide();
  $(".date2").show();
  });
});
</script>
```

**EDIT:**
I had to change things a bit, realized it wasn't working properly

Answer (score 0):

> [The date type doesn't support placeholder attribute.](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-input-element.html#input-type-attr-summary) Also, the
>   WebKit implementation says it's **[fixed.](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/html/DateInputType.cpp?rev=130375#L161)**

*related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12869288/3625883*

you should use a label instead.  (simple jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/7L4tb/ )

```
<label for="test">Test Date :</label>
<input id="test" type="date" value="2014-07-14" />
```

Comment: I need the field itself to be changed, not the label around it.

Comment: It can't be changed with placeholder attribute, give a look to the list I posted.

Comment: I know that, the question I'm asking is if there is a way to not have the value in a "yyyy-mm-dd" format.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible, see this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format

Answer (score 0):

Placeholder isn't supported.
Value should be in [RFC3339](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/references.html#refsRFC3339) format **yyyy-mm-dd**.

For full details, see http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html

**Edit now that I read the question correctly...**

No, the field must contain a well formatted date. It cannot contain text. Either use a text field and add something like jQuery UI's DatePicker, or use some awful jQuery hackery with absolutely positioned div's covering the datefields - if yuo absolutely must use a date field.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var i = 0;

$('input[type="date"]').each(function () {
    var dfEl = $(this);
    var str = '<div class="datePlaceholder" id="divph' + i + '">Choose a date</div>';
    dfEl.after(str);
    var phEl = $('#divph' + i);

    var dateFieldPos = dfEl.offset();
    phEl.css({
        top: dateFieldPos.top + 1,
        left: dateFieldPos.left + 1,
        width: $(this).width() + 1,
        height: $(this).height() + 1
    });

    phEl.click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        dfEl.focus();
    });

    dfEl.blur(function () {
        if (!dfEl.val()) {
            phEl.show();
        }
    });
    i++;
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/AY2mp/1/

Comment: I know that, I am trying to figure out if there is a workaround to changing the input value.

Comment: @hannah Apolgies, I misread the question. Updated my answer. Short = No, long = yes with hackery. Don't do this. Use a textfield and a datepicker control. My 2 pence...